# How to memoize a function with Options?

Tags: memoization

Consider the following modified fibonacci function:

```
tempHist = $History
$History = 0
ClearAll[fibon]
Options[fibon] = {k -> 1}
fibon[0] = 0;
fibon[1] = 1;
fibon[n_, OptionsPattern[]]:= fibon[n-1] + OptionValue[k] * fibon[n-2]

fibon[30] // Timing           (* {4.111894, 832040} *)
fibon[30, k -> 2] // Timing   (* {4.161676, 1149851} *)
```

The modification involves a coefficent that multiplies the second term of the 
recursive definition. Can the idiom `f[x_]:=f[x]= ...` be used to implement 
memoization in this case?

I tried with no luck the following naive approaches for `c`-aching `fibon`

```
ClearAll[cfibon]
Options[cfibon] = {k -> 1}
cfibon[0] = 0;
cfibon[1] = 1;
cfibon[n_, OptionsPattern[]]:= cfibon[n, OptionsPattern[]] = cfibon[n-1] + OptionValue[k] * cfibon[n-2]

cfibon[30] // Timing          (* {2.1999999997746045*^-5, 832040} *)
cfibon[30, k -> 2] // Timing  (* {2.899999999961267*^-5, 832040} *)
```

*Something* is being memoized, but this is not the wanted behavior (note that the two
calls return the same value `832040`, the second call is meant return `1149851`). 
Here is another try:

```
ClearAll[cfibon]
Options[cfibon] = {k -> 1}
cfibon[0] = 0;
cfibon[1] = 1;
cfibon[n_, OptionsPattern[]]:= cfibon[n, k -> OptionValue[k]] = cfibon[n-1] + OptionValue[k] * cfibon[n-2]

cfibon[30] // Timing
(* {10.664260999999998, 832040} *)

cfibon[30, k -> 2] // Timing
(* {10.677505, 1149851} *)
```

Now, the results are as expected, by the computation is slower than the 
non-cached version! So...

How to memoize a function with `Options`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### The case at hand

Here is one possibility:

```
ClearAll[fibon]
Options[fibon] = {k -> 1}
fibon[0, OptionsPattern[]] = 0;
fibon[1, OptionsPattern[]] = 1;

fibon[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] /; ! OrderedQ[{opts}] :=
   fibon[n, Sequence @@ Sort[{opts}]];
fibon[n_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
   fibon[n, opts] = 
       fibon[n - 1, opts] + OptionValue[k]*fibon[n - 2, opts]
```

So, for example:

```
fibon[30]

(*  832040  *)

fibon[30,k->2]

(* 357913941 *)
```

Note that I added a rule which sorts the options, and I explicitly assumed the two sets of options the same when they are only different by the order of options. This assumption could be improved by accounting for some options not present explicitly but being the same due to defaults.

#### General meta-programming solution

The above version has the following limitations:

- Default option values not accounted for
- Has to explicitly pass the options to inner calls to self
- It is not general enough (which is ok for a specific problem, but not for a general approach). Although one can see that some of the code does not really depend on the specifics of the problem, the above form does not allow one to easily factor that out.

Here I will address these limitations of the previous version, and show how we can achieve a fairly complete automation of this task for a wide class of problems by using meta-programming and code generation.

Here is a code-generating function that would generate the full memoizing code from simpler version not involving options:

```
ClearAll[optionMemo];
SetAttributes[optionMemo, HoldAll];
optionMemo[sym_Symbol, {defs___}, defOptions : {___?OptionQ}] :=
  Module[{},
    ClearAll[sym];
    Options[sym] = defOptions;
    sym[args : Except[_?OptionQ] ..., opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
      With[{
        newopts =
          Sort @ DeleteDuplicates[
             {opts}~Join~Options[sym], 
             First@#1 == First@#2 &]
         },
         sym[args, Sequence @@ newopts] /; newopts =!= {opts}
      ];
    sym[args : Except[_?OptionQ] ..., opts : OptionsPattern[]]/;!OrderedQ[{opts}] :=
       sym[args, Sequence @@ Sort[{opts}]];

    sym[args : Except[_?OptionQ] ..., opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
      Block[{sym, options = Options[sym]},
         Options[sym] = options;
         defs;
         sym[args]
      ]
  ];
```

It takes the name of the symbol, the list of code statements which produce the relevant definitions, and the list of options for this symbol. It works by generating the boilerplate code, but also it relies on a rather interesting technique where a function `Block`-s itself and creates some definitions locally inside `Block`. What we buy by this construct here:

- We don't have to pass options to inner recursive calls
- We can still globally call `OptionVaulue` as before, with a single argument, and this will work.
- The memoization only happens during the computation, to speed it up, but all the memoized values are cleared by `Block` at the end, automatically;

So, here is how we use it: first generate the boilerplate code

```
optionMemo[
  fibon,
  {
     fibon[0] = 0,
     fibon[1] = 1,
     fibon[m_] := fibon[m] = fibon[m - 1] + OptionValue[k]*fibon[m - 2]
  },
  {k -> 1, i -> 2}
]
```

and now use it as before:

```
fibon[30]

(*  832040  *)

fibon[30,k->2]

(* 357913941 *)
```

The `optionMemo` construct should be general enough to handle many similar problems.

Comment: Of course what Leonid did is much better... :)

Comment: Leonid, can you comment on the obviously wrong things that I did? It would help developing a better intuition for how Options are handled.

Comment: I absolutely admit that this comment is nitpicking, but we are probably already talking about corner cases anyway: I think sorting the options could be problematic in cases where the same option is given more than once. E.g. compare `fibon[30,k->2,k->3]` with `fibon[30,k->3,k->2]`, the results are probably not what one would expect considering how options usually work...

Comment: @AlbertRetey See my update with a meta-programming code - it takes care of that as well (as of many other things).

Comment: @Ryogi Your biggest problem was that you did not pass options down to recursive calls, *but* you used the option in the memoized part as `cfibon[n, k -> OptionValue[k]] = ...`, so your memoized definitions were actually never used.

Comment: @Leonid: I think I must be proud: at least it took me a few seconds less to recognize a problem than it took you to solve it (and some others) :-)

Comment: @AlbertRetey Oh, come on :-)

Comment: @AlbertRetey But this is the first problem I have seen where the self-blocking technique brings more than just convenience to not pass some arguments explicitly - here also one can globally call single-argument `OptionValue` across the full recursive execution stack. I think this is pretty cool.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: it took me a while to understand what you do and to appreciate the self-blocking part I needed your comment. It's really interesting, I never even thought about doing that. Seriously, I would upvote more than once if I could...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Thanks :-). I use self-blocking from time to time, when I want to avoid tedious passing of some arguments. Basically, a function blocks itself inside its external call, then defines itself there inside `Block`, and then executes. This allows me to embed those arguments which don't change,right to the body of those definitions, so they can be simpler. But, as I said, here we have an extra bonus of global access to all `OptionValue`-s (one - arg "magical" form of them) across the execution stack, which seems pretty neat to me.

Comment: Great answer @LeonidShifrin, thank you.

Comment: @Ryogi Glad I could help. Thanks for the accept.

Answer (score 3):

This should do what you want:

```
ClearAll[cfibon]
Options[cfibon] = {k -> 1};
cfibon[0,OptionsPattern[]] = 0;
cfibon[1,OptionsPattern[]] = 1;
cfibon[n_, options : OptionsPattern[]] := cfibon[n, options] = 
  cfibon[n - 1,options] + OptionValue[k]*cfibon[n - 2,options];

cfibon[30] // Timing
(*{0., 832040}*)
cfibon[30, k -> 2] // Timing
(*{0., 357913941}*)
```

Answer (score 1):

This addresses your title more than your content. FWIW I have found options memoization occasionally useful in interfaces. For example if you have a control that recalculates something, with the control selection being an option value, there may be no real need to keep redoing the calculation. So memoization with this option can be implemented. There may be other options that will not change after evaluation so these can be left as is.

Here is an example:

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1, g},

 Column[{

   PopupMenu[
    Dynamic[x], {1 -> "choice 1", 2 -> "choice 2", 3 -> "choice 3"}],

   Dynamic[
    Information[g];
    g[2, Opt -> x]
    ]

   }],
 Initialization :> {g[x_, OptionsPattern[{Opt -> 1, Colour -> Red}]] :=
     g[x, Opt -> OptionValue[Opt]] = 
     Framed[OptionValue[Opt]*x^2, FrameStyle -> OptionValue[Colour]]}]
```

[image]