# Orderless storage of tabulated function values

Tags: function-construction, data, options, associations, language-design

I would like to elaborate on my previous question [Function of arguments given in non-fixed order](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/62887/function-of-arguments-given-in-non-fixed-order) and a relevant related one [Best practice of passing a large number of parameters to functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/55833/best-practice-of-passing-a-large-number-of-parameters-to-functions)

I find that neither `Options` nor `Association` are perfect for what I need to do here, I am hoping to find some hint to a better solution here.

I have to handle a large set of data that are essentially the results of the evaluation of a very time-consuming function on some points and that now I want to store. What I want to achieve is a quick way to recall the results that I have stored and a quick way to store them when I evaluate the function.

Ideally I would like to achieve a point where I can do

```
MyStorage[lot of parameters]=LengthyFunction[lot of parameters]
```

so that I can recall the results as

```
MyStorage[lot of parameters]
```

If the list of parameters is small this is not a problem, you just use the two lines above. But when the list of parameters gets long it comes the trouble, because you need to put `lot of parameters` in the same order as the function is defined. This also comes with the additional difficulty that `MyStorage[2,3,5]` completely hides to you the meaning of the entries in the arguments sequence.

So I thought it was best to use something like `MyStorage[{x->2,y->3,z->5}]`, which makes very explicit at what point you are calling the function. This, however, is not a solution, because the order of the arguments still matters. In fact defining `MyStorage[{x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 5}] = {a, d, b}`
then you can recall the stored value only by `MyStorage[{x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 5}]` and not by `MyStorage[{y -> 3, z -> 5, x -> 2}]`

Using associations does not help either, because one runs in the exact same issue of ordering. So I am left with `Options` as the sole `Orderless` way to go. Unfortunately `Options` cannot be used directly in this example, unless I have missed something. The shortest way to use `Options` that I can think of is to use a **"Put" and a "Get" function**, that take Options as inputs and then do the job using an ordinary "ordered" function for storage of the type `MyStorage[2,3,5]`.

```
    MyStoragePut[opt : OptionsPattern[], value_] := Module[{point},
      point = {x, y, z} /. opt;
      MyStorage[Sequence[point]] = value;
    ]
```

at this point you can fill in the storage without recalling the order of the variables. Indeed `MyStoragePut[{y -> 3, z -> 99, x -> 2}, {2, 3, 34}]` followed by `MyStoragePut[{x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 99}, {2, 23, 34}]` would replace if the value at `{x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 99}`.

To retrieve the values I define the "Get" method

```
   MyStorageGet[opt : OptionsPattern[]] := Module[{point},
    point = {x, y, z} /. opt;
   MyStorage[Sequence[point]]
   ]
```

which also works regardless of the order in which the values are specified: `MyStorageGet[{x -> 2, y -> 3, z -> 99}]` and `MyStorageGet[{x -> 2, z -> 99, y -> 3}]` give the same result stored in the symbol `MyStorage[2,3,99]`.

*I wanted to ask* if this is a dumb way of reinventing a wheel that is already (better) implemented in Mathematica or there are anyways better strategies to achieve this orderless data storage and retrieval.

Thanks for your inputs,
Roberto

Comment: In rescue of `Association` I should say that they are useful to take a long list of Options, and change the value of one of the options and obtain back a list of options. Say by doing  `ChangeOptionValue[mykey_, Val_, BaseParameters_] := 
 Module[{myass = (Association[Sequence[BaseParameters]])},
  myass[mykey] = Val;
  Normal[myass]
  ]`

Comment: Related: [(21354)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/21354/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have found something that may solve your problem.  I discovered today:

```
Data`UnorderedAssociation
```

This is an undocumented function that appears to work like `Association` at least in a limited set of operations, yet it puts its keys into a consistent order:

```
Data`UnorderedAssociation /@ Permutations@{"d" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "a" -> 3, "c" -> 4}

SameQ @@ %
```

> ```
> {<|"a" -> 3, "d" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 4|>,
>  <|"a" -> 3, "d" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 4|>, . . . }
>
> True
> ```

- Note that this order is not the same as used by `Sort`.

The expression may be constructed piecewise and it still is the same:

```
uno = Data`UnorderedAssociation[];

uno["d"] = 1;
uno["c"] = 4;
uno["b"] = 2;
uno["a"] = 3;

uno
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> 3, "d" -> 1, "b" -> 2, "c" -> 4|>
> ```

Although formatted like `Association` the expression retains a different structure:

```
uno // FullForm
```

> ```
> Data`UnorderedAssociation[Rule["a", 3], Rule["d", 1], Rule["b", 2], Rule["c", 4]]
> ```

Comment: Thanks for digging out this undocumented feature. I think is going to be useful!

Answer (score 3):

Using `Orderless`:

```
ClearAll[f]
SetAttributes[f, Orderless]
f[x[x_], y[y_], z[z_]] := {x, y, z}
f[x[1], z[3], y[2]]
(* Out: {1, 2, 3} *)
```

You have to make sure that the heads (`x`, `y`, `z`) do not have values.

If you prefer it you can also write the definition with prefix notation

```
f[x@x_, y@y_, z@z_] := {x, y, z}
f[x@1, z@3, y@2]
```

which is just a little bit shorter.

EDIT. I realize now that the question is also about quick lookup. george2079 has it right, you should use [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/731) for this. So it would look like this:

```
f[x@x_, y@y_, z@z_] := f[x,y,z] = {x, y, z}
```

This way it won't repeat calculations that is has already performed, regardless of in which order you put the arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Clear[f]
 f[rules_] := f[Sort[rules]] = (Pause[2]; g[ x  , y ] /. rules )
 f[{y -> 2, x -> 1}] // AbsoluteTiming
 f[{x -> 1, y -> 2}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {2.012387, g[1, 2]}
>
> {0., g[1, 2]}

Comment: But if you have more than two parameters and try another order of the parameters that is not canonical then it will run the function again unnecessarily, I believe.